# How to increment a field value in Firestore using Cloud Functions using Javascript?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Cloud function which I am trying to get to increment a field in Firestore:

```
exports.incrementUpvotes = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    async function incrementValue() {
        const Id = data.thisId;
        const increment = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);
        const docRef = admin.firestore().collection('posts').doc(Id)
        
        docRef.update({ upvoteCount: increment })
    };
    return incrementValue()
})
```

I have tried lots of variations of the above. Each time it fails with this error: Uncaught (in promise) Error: INTERNAL

I'm calling it just using this:

```
const incrementUpvotes = getFunctions.httpsCallable('incrementUpvotes')
```

EDIT: getFunctions is an export from my Firebase.js ie. firebase.functions()

and then this in a function:

```
incrementUpvotes({thisId})
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're neither returning anything nor using `await` in your `incrementValue` function, which means that it ends up returning `undefined`.

Since `docRef.update` is an asynchronous call, you'll want to either `await` that or return the promise it returns.

So:

```
function incrementValue() { //  Removed async
    const Id = data.thisId;
    const increment = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1); //  Use admin
    const docRef = admin.firestore().collection('posts').doc(Id)
    
    return docRef.update({ upvoteCount: increment })  //  Added return
};
```

Comment: Hello Frank. Thank you for your reply. upvoteCount is not incrementing. There are no errors now, though. I've tried a few different things, hence my delayed response, but to no avail. One thing (and I am a beginner) - the function name is greyed out. There's nothing actually 'calling' it. Is this an issue?

Comment: Ah yes, as you discovered yourself there was an _additional_ problem in the `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)` (which has to be `admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)`). I updated my answer. I'm quite sure that the lack of handling of async was also a problem though.

Comment: @MattHeslington Anything else needed here?

Comment: Hello Frank, I posted the answer/solution and referenced your answer on Jun 16th. Thanks for your help

Comment: If you find a mistake in an answer, it is custom to either fix that (there's an edit link under it) or point it out in a comment. Posting your own answer based on what I showed, fixing the remaining problem, and then accepting your own answer, is not the best way to motivate people to help you going forward. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I didn't see your comment about updating your answer. I've deleted my answer and accepted yours. As you said in your comment, you updated your answer based on what I found worked. (^o^)y